# In jQuery, disable a submit button in a keyup function

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I need to perform a search for certain email clients in an input, if the email client matches then I need to disable the button that submits the form.

```
 $('#Email').keyup(function(e){
    var email =  $('#Email');
    var emailValue = $('#Email').val();
    var invalidEmails = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.in', 'aol.com', 'abc.com']

    for(var i = 0; i <= invalidEmails.length; i++){
      if( emailValue.toLowerCase().indexOf( invalidEmails[i]) >= 0){
        $('.corporativo-invalid').show();
        email.toggleClass('invalid-email');
        $('#register-button').prop("disabled",true);
        //e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $('#register-button').prop("disabled",false);
      }
    }
  });
```

The line that does not seem to work is this one:

```
$('#register-button').prop("disabled",true);
```

What is confusing to me is that if instead of a keyup event, I do a click event on the button, with the same function then this works? This example does work:

```
$('#register-button').click(function(e){
    var email =  $('#Email');
    var emailValue = $('#Email').val();
    var invalidEmails = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.co.in', 'aol.com', 'abc.com']

    for(var i = 0; i <= invalidEmails.length; i++){
      if( emailValue.toLowerCase().indexOf( invalidEmails[i]) >= 0){
        $('.corporativo-invalid').show();
        email.toggleClass('invalid-email')
        $('#register-button').prop("disabled",true);
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $('#register-button').prop("disabled",false);
      }
    }
  });
```

But I would need to use the keyup event.

The HTML:

```
<form class="needs-validation" id="register-form" novalidate>
    <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="breadcrumbs small"><span class="back">‹</span> Volver atrás</a>
    <h1>Regístrate</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Correo eléctronico" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback correo-inavlid">Por favor, introduce un correo electrónico</div>
        <div class="corporativo-invalid">Por favor, introduce un correo corporativo</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor, introduce una contraseña</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-sm-flex text-center justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <button class="btn login-form-button" type="submit" id="register-button">QUIERO REGISTRARME <span>›</span></button>
        <p class="small">¿Ya estás registrado? <a href="login.html">Inicia sesión <span>›</span></a></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the attribute type="submit" to type="button"

```
if( emailValue.toLowerCase().indexOf( invalidEmails[i]) >= 0){
    $('.corporativo-invalid').show();
    email.toggleClass('invalid-email')
    $('#register-button').attr("type","button");
  } else {
    $('#register-button').attr("type","submit");
  }
```